# Get Activity name dynamically - android

Tags: android, android-activity, introspection

I'd like to get the name of the current `Activity` to be sent along in the URI of an `HttpRequest`. Is there a way to do this without referring specifically to the `Activity`?

I know I can do `myActivity.class.toString()` but this is just a less efficient way of hard coding "myActivity" since I'm making a static reference to my `Activity`. Is there a more general way to do this using something like 'this' (which btw doesn't actually work here because it returns more information than what's desired).

Comment: I don't know that this works, but can't you just use `this.getClass().getSimpleName()` instead?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Use `this.getClass().getSimpleName()` to get the name of the Activity.

From the comments, if you're in the context of an `OnClickListener` (or other inner class), specify the class manually:

`MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()`

Comment: That's a good suggestion but not what I'm looking for. It works within onCreate(), but not from within my onClickListener which is where I would like to get the Activity name. If I can't no solution is better than using a constant string.

Comment: To do this within an onClickListener, you would do "MyActivityName.this.getClass().getSimpleName()"

Comment: You should note that if you are going to use ProGuard, your class name will get obfuscated and the obfuscated name is what you'll receive on the backend.

Comment: And you can use `MainActivity::class.java.name` in kotlin.

Answer (score 23):

For purists out there who may not want to use reflection, an alternative way is to use the `PackageManager` as follows:

```
PackageManager packageManager = activity.getPackageManager();
try {
  ActivityInfo info = packageManager.getActivityInfo(activity.getComponentName(), 0);
  Log.e("app", "Activity name:" + info.name);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However this seems like a lot of work just to do the same as `getClass().getName()` (and not even `getSimpleName()`). But I guess it may be useful for someone who wants more information about the activity than just the class name.

Answer (score 7):

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
this.currentActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
Log.i( "CURRENT Activity ",  currentActivity);
```

Comment: getRunningTasks is deprecated.

Comment: This Code crashed Android 12, Android 13 devices.

Answer (score 5):

**First:** open your `manifest.xml` file

you will find your package name i.e. `"com.company.projectname"`

**Then:** lets say your activity name is `MainActivity`

```
MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName() >output> "com.company.projectname.MainActivity"
```

**OR**

```
MainActivity.class.getSimpleName() >output> "MainActivity"
```

**OR**

```
MainActivity.class.getName() >output> "com.company.projectname.MainActivity"
```

Answer (score 1):

### **For Xamarin**

```
string GetActivityClassName(Activity activity) //Receiving LoginActivity
{
    //ComponentName
    activity.ComponentName; //Output: "md5101a0260d0a0e5d40a0a9009be09b0c2.LoginActivity"

    //LocalClassName
    activity.LocalClassName; //Output: "md5101a0260d0a0e5d40a0a9009be09b0c2.LoginActivity"

    //Java.Lang.Class.FromType.SimpleName
    Java.Lang.Class.FromType(activity.GetType()).SimpleName; //Output "LoginActivity"

    //Type.Name
    activity.GetType().Name; //Output "LoginActivity"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using Kotlin, try this:

```
this.javaClass.name
```